# Get clientHeight of div using Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to get the [clientHeight](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_clientheight.asp) of a div? How do I do this  in Angular? (I don't care if it's bad practice at this point)

I have tried a thousand things, some of which can be seen in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VMeFAMEnc0XeQWJiLHm?p=preview). The code below works outside of a controller, but not for clientHeight:

```
    $scope.myElem = angular.element(document.getElementById('testDiv')); 
    $scope.myAttr = $scope.myElem.attr('name');
```

I don't know how to get the attributes from within a directive. All examples seem to only use link with named attributes. I won't be setting the clientHeight, I just need to return it.

Comment: In your directive you can get the clientHeight this way : `elem[0].clientHeight`. Do your DOM work in your directive, not your controller.

Comment: You are awesome Eric. Why is it zero though? Cleaned plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0VMeFAMEnc0XeQWJiLHm?p=preview

Comment: I'm going to guess in this. Because `example-directive` is not a `native` (if I can call it like that) element so it doesn't have those properties. If you want it to have a height, you can change your directive to `<div example-directive></div>` and change your `restrict` to `A`. So if you do those changes and add some content to the div it will log some height.

Comment: @EricMartinez just tested that in my Plunker and yes, you are correct

Comment: @Eric Martinez: I feel like an ass asking, but can you glance at this and let me know why the scrollTop property might be failing to show? 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyFI13DN5Q38qSGAdtf2?p=preview

Comment: That's because when you call `elem` you're calling the `example-directive` div, and the div with the scrollbar is a child of it. So you have two choices : in your current directive get the first children and bind (using `bind` or `on`) the `scroll` event or you can create a second directive for the div contained in div.html and get the `scrollTop` directly.

Comment: @Eric Martinez: You really made my day, honestly. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a directive would be the easiest way. The DOM is fully realised in the `link` (post link) function so element properties should be available.

For example

```
.directive('logClientHeight', function($log) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $log.debug(element.prop('clientHeight'));
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhv4n0FYt1uB7TwUiTVj?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Note that for the element to have typical [element properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Properties), it should be a typical element.

<sub>Thanks [Eric Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933038/eric-martinez) for pointing that out.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much, up voted. Might have another question or two if you are willing to help. Trying to do this http://jsfiddle.net/rs3prkfm/ in angular. Your example text hits home, I have been at this all day. Guess that's what I get for not knowing fundamentals.

Comment: Can you take a look at one last thing please? I absolutely understand if you don't though and appreciate the help I already got. With that said, I need the 'ScrollTop' property: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZyFI13DN5Q38qSGAdtf2?p=preview

Any ideas on why it's stuck at 0?

Comment: Didn't save update, my bad. But it seems like it either doesn't get it or doesn't update it. Old link still works, just with saved changes now.

Comment: @VSO because your element isn't the thing that's scrolling; the `<div>` inside it is. Fixed here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVuhefNxTKydrJdyLn67?p=preview

Comment: I know my "thank you" repetitions are redundant at this point, but you really helped me out here.